# malloc_usable_size() returns the wrong size

Tags: c, memory, malloc

I want to know the size allocated by malloc.
I have written the source code below.

### test.c

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <malloc.h>
void main(void)
{
    uint8_t *test;

    test = (uint8_t *)malloc(sizeof(uint8_t)*4);
    printf("sizeof(test) = %d\n",malloc_usable_size(test));

    free(test); 
}
```

I expected size to be 4.
But the result is 12.

```
sizeof(test) = 12
```

Can you tell me what's wrong?
I hope that size 4 correctly comes out.

Comment: Read [Notes of malloc_usable_size](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc_usable_size.3.html)

Comment: No, malloc_usable_size() returns the right size.  What is wrong is your expectation of what the right size should be.

Comment: What's missing so far: `malloc_usable_size()` is for debugging, not for your main code. Even if the size is actually larger, you're not *supposed* to use it.

Comment: Don't think of `malloc_usable_size` as a way of determining the size of allocation. For multiple reasons -  1) It is not portable. 2) You are supposed to keep track of your allocations yourself. Since you called malloc, you know what size you had passed. If you are having a hard time remembering it, do some book keeping. One way could be to allocate extra space for `size_t` in the begining of the allocation and put the size there. That actual size that you passed to `malloc`. Others have made it clear why it returns 12 and not 4.

Comment: @user2371524 "Even if the size is actually larger, you're not supposed to use it." I love how the name of the function (`malloc_usable_size`) literally says that that is the usable size.

Comment: void main(void)
Bad practice please avoid this
-1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
malloc_usable_size(test)
```

The value returned by above function is  not fixed as you requested. it may be greater than the requested size of the allocation depending upon the cpu byte ordering and alignment. this is totally depend upon the underlaying implementation.

Comment: CPU alignes requested memory to type size or cache line size, so in your case 8 bytes are added

Comment: @Andre I think it more likely that the alignment (_in this case_ -- it will vary) is on 16-byte boundaries. The "true" allocation will be 16 bytes; four will be used internally (e.g. pointer to next block) leaving 12 bytes [sort of] usable.

Comment: That's true, i suppose all the space needed to administer the variable internally is added. So the size returned varies on based on CPU/OS administration needs and alignment requirements.

Comment: @Andre The size returned is the number of usable bytes that one can write to "without ill effects", excluding bytes needed to manage the allocation.

"The value returned by malloc_usable_size() may be greater than the requested size of the allocation because of alignment and minimum size constraints.  Although the excess bytes can be overwritten by the application without ill effects, this is not good programming practice: the number of excess bytes in an allocation depends on the underlying implementation."

[link](man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc_usable_size.3.html)