# Get size of a simulated array using malloc

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a simulated 2D array using pointers with malloc and I want to get the size of that array, since sizeof() returns me the size of the pointer.
My code (ANSI C):

```
void main(){
    int s1=10;
    int s2=15;
    int ** rack=(int**)malloc(s1*sizeof(int**));
    for(int i=0; i<s1; i++) rack[i]=(int*)malloc(s2*sizeof(int*));
}
```

I want a function (may by system, may do it myself) this way:

```
size(rack)    //returns 10
size(rack[0]) //returns 15
```

Thanks in advance! (For more info I use GNU/Linux)

Comment: Note that [pointer to pointer array is not really 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42094465/694733). Also, ANSI C refers to old, outdated version of C; if you are on Linux it's quite possible that you could upgrade to C11.

Comment: A good habit is not to do the `sizeof` in `malloc` with the the type but with the object that the pointer is supposed to point to `malloc(s1*sizeof *rack)`. Also in C you shouldn't cast the return of `malloc` and friends.

Comment: You allocate the wrong amount of space in the mallocs

Comment: If you are given a pointer that was assigned/initialized with the value returned by `malloc` there is no (portable) way to find out how much memory was requested originally. These links may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28854641/4386427 or http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc_usable_size.3.html or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44581168/malloc-usable-size-returns-the-wrong-size

Comment: I'm not going to say you can't, but in C, you allocate the memory and you are responsible for tracking the allocation. There isn't a simple library function that will tell you how much memory you allocated for variable `X` earlier in your code. (and with multiple functions, and scopes, that information may not be available at runtime)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get size of 2D array pointed by a double pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12965359/how-to-get-size-of-2d-array-pointed-by-a-double-pointer)

Comment: [see: 2-D Matrix with `malloc()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46512314/graph-with-adjacency-matrix-in-c/46513988#46513988), and consider to `free()` allocated memory at last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the way you allocate memory for your 2D array is wrong. You need to change it to :

```
void main(){
    int s1 = 10;
    int s2 = 15;
    int** rack = malloc(s1*sizeof(int*));
    if (rack == NULL)
        return;
    for(int i=0; i<s1; i++) {
        rack[i]=malloc(s2*sizeof(int));
        if (rack[i] == NULL)
            return;
    }

    ... 

    free(rack);
    return;
}
```

Remember to always [check malloc's result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26831981/should-i-check-if-malloc-was-successful) and also [not to cast malloc's result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

In order to get your array's size, you can print `s1*s2*sizeof(int)` as you have allocated `s1` pointers to `int`, each of which holds `s2` `int`s.

Comment: Please note that you are *not* freeing all the memory that you have allocated.

Comment: @Bob__ I did not because I answered only to the part of the allocation. I assumed that the OP freed his memory but showed us a minimal part.

Comment: Due to differences in the range of `int` and `size_t`, `s1*s2*sizeof(int)` can overflow while `sizeof(int)*s1*s2*` does not.  IAC, better to use `size_t` for array indexing and size than `int`.